# SQL count trouble

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that I select "project managers" from and pull data about them.

Each of them has a number of "clients" that they manage.

Clients are linked to their project manager by name.

For example: John Smith has 3 Clients. Each of those Clients have his name in a row called "manager".

Here's what a simple version of the table looks like:

```
name       | type    | manager
--------------------------------------
John Smith | manager |
Client 1   | client  | John Smith
Client 2   | client  | John Smith
Client 3   | client  | John Smith
John Carry | manager |
Client 4   | client  | John Carry
Client 5   | client  | John Carry
Client 6   | client  | John Carry
```

How can I return the following data?

John Smith - 3 Clients

John Carry - 3 Clients

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use a self-join and the `count()` aggregate function to get the result:

```
select t.name,
  count(t1.name) TotalClients
from yourtable t
inner join yourtable t1
  on t.name = t1.manager
group by t.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d72a87/2).

If you want the result to include the `Clients` text, then you the `CONCAT()` function:

```
select t.name,
  concat(count(t1.name), ' Clients') TotalClients
from yourtable t
inner join yourtable t1
  on t.name = t1.manager
group by t.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d72a87/3)

If you want to add a WHERE clause based on the `type`, then you will use:

```
select t.name,
  concat(count(t1.name), ' Clients') TotalClients
from yourtable t
inner join yourtable t1
  on t.name = t1.manager
where t.type = 'manager'
group by t.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d72a87/11)

Comment: perfect. where can i add in a custom where condition?

Comment: @maxhud What do you mean?  You should be able to add a WHERE clause as needed

Comment: @maxhud That link is the same as the one I posted, I don't see any differences.

Comment: @maxhud the where clause goes before the GROUP BY -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d72a87/11

Comment: I don't think that code you use to insert table values is correct. That's the reason of problems in query.

Comment: @NaNa I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: when I run the sql query from my mysql administrative interface, it works correctly, however the php script selects the last user in the count. for example the php script returns client 3 as the name rather than john smith. the sql query is the same on the php script and all I do is echo $row['name']

Comment: @maxhud I am not a PHP developer so I can't answer that question.  If you have an issue with PHP code then post a new question.  I can only help with the SQL code. :)

Comment: @maxhud Well, your question was about accomplishing something on MySQL, you never said anything about PHP. If this works (as you said it does) for the requirements of this question, then that should be all (and you should probably mark this answer as accepted)

Comment: @bluefeet: table creating code from sqlfiddle example. this is a problem of insufficient table normalisation. It'd be much easier if there were 2 tables instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a join here. A simple `group by` can do the work:

```
Select manager, count(*) as totalClients from yourtable group by 1, order by 2 desc
```

This will list all managers and the number of client's they have. The manager with the most clients comes first. This way you omit the join and the query will be faster.

Between the `from` and the `group by` you can add `where` predicates to filter clients or managers or other columns.

Answer (score 0):

if Manager is available,

select count(1),Manager
from Table_Project
group by Manager

If I am not missing any information,then above query should produce required result.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select manager, concat(count(*), ' Clients') TotalClients
from yourtable 
where manager is not null
group by manager
```